# Python KeyboardInterrupt is causing a file corruption

Tags: python, xml, keyboardinterrupt

I have a piece of code responsible for cleaning a XML file. Parsing errors are handled (the file is ignored).

However, I interrupted this function with `ctrl`+`C` and it ended up corrupting the currently processed file (the file content was erased):

```py
import lxml.etree as ET
from pathlib import Path


def foo(path: str):
  try:
    tree = ET.parse(path)
    # Some code that reads and modifies the tree...
  except ET.ParseError:
    return
  Path(path).write_text(ET.tostring(tree))
```

**Is there some way to do cleanup code on `KeyboardInterrupt`?**

For instance, should I handle `KeyboardInterrupt` in an except bloc to avoid writing? Maybe I can use an `else` bloc after the error handling to only write when no error occurred:

```py
def foo(path: str):
  try:
    tree = ET.parse(path)
    # Some code that reads and modifies the tree...
  except ET.ParseError:
    return
  else:
    Path(path).write_text(ET.tostring(tree))
```

Comment: I just tried with a else bloc but corruption still occurs.

Comment: maybe you should use `except KeyboardInterrupt: Path(path).write_text(ET.tostring(tree))`

Comment: or maybe you should use `with open(...) as fh: fh.write()` and it should close file when there will be problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to check `KeyboardInterrupt` while writing the file and re-attempt the write operation before exiting:

```py
import lxml.etree as ET
from pathlib import Path
from sys import exit

def foo(path: str):
  try:
    tree = ET.parse(path)
    # Some code that reads and modifies the tree...
  except ET.ParseError:
    return
  else:
    content = ET.tostring(tree)
    try:
      Path(path).write_text(content)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      Path(path).write_text(content)
      exit()
```

Putting that code in an else clause makes sure that previous operations did not fail, thus the data is valid at this point.